# undefined reference to `sys_getprocs' when getting number of processes in Xv6

Tags: operating-system, system-calls, xv6

I was playing with the Xv6 OS lab and trying to implement a simple syscall `getprocs()` that returns the number of processes currently running. I finished the work pretty soon but I kept getting the following error message when I was trying to do `make qemu`:

```
riscv64-unknown-elf-ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _entry; defaulting to 0000000080000000
riscv64-unknown-elf-ld: kernel/syscall.o: in function `syscall':
/xv6-labs-2020/kernel/syscall.c:143: undefined reference to `sys_getprocs'
riscv64-unknown-elf-ld: kernel/syscall.o: in function `.LANCHOR0':
syscall.c:(.rodata+0xc8): undefined reference to `sys_getprocs'
make: *** [Makefile:94: kernel/kernel] Error 1
```

Here's what I did.

- I declared a user function `int getprocs(void);` in `user/user.h`.
- I then created a new file `kernel/getprocs.c`, where the system call interface is implemented as the following:

```
#include "types.h"
#include "param.h"
#include "memlayout.h"
#include "riscv.h"
#include "spinlock.h"
#include "proc.h"
#include "defs.h"
#include "syscall.h"

extern int get_procs(void);

uint64
sys_getprocs(void)
{
  return get_procs();
}
```

- Following this, I went to `kernel/proc.c` to add the actual `int get_procs(void)` that counts all the used processes in the system:

```
int
get_procs(void)
{
  int num_procs = 0;
  
  struct proc *p;

  for(p = proc; p < &proc[NPROC]; p++) {
    acquire(&p->lock);
    if(p->state != UNUSED) num_procs++;
    release(&p->lock);
  }

  return num_procs;

}
```

- I assigned a new syscall number for my new function in `kernel/syscall.h` like this: `#define SYS_getprocs 22`.
- Having assigned a new syscall number, I went to modify the system call table in `syscall.c`. Here I made two modifications:

1. add `[SYS_getprocs]   sys_getprocs,` to the `static uint64 (*syscalls[])(void)`. I didn't understand exactly how this work but I added it anyway.
2. within function `void syscall()`, I changed it to:

```
void
syscall(void)
{
  int num;
  struct proc *p = myproc();

  num = p->trapframe->a7;
  if(num == SYS_getprocs) p->trapframe->a0 = sys_getprocs();
  else if(num > 0 && num < NELEM(syscalls) && syscalls[num]) {
    p->trapframe->a0 = syscalls[num]();
  } else {
    printf("%d %s: unknown sys call %d\n",
            p->pid, p->name, num);
    p->trapframe->a0 = -1;
  }
}
```

This should handle the newly added system call.

- Finally, I added a new mapping in `user/usys.pl`: `entry("getprocs");`

I reviewed over and over again, still clueless where it went wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you update the `Makefile`? I guess it misses the line `$K/getprocs.o` in `OBJS` definition.

Comment: @Mathieu Yes this is the issue! Already got it up and running, thanks!

Comment: Ok, so I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forgot to ask for compilation of `getprocs.o` into `Makefile`:

just add the line `$K/getprocs.o` in `OBJS` definition:

```
K=kernel
U=user

OBJS = \
  ...
  $K/main.o \
  $K/vm.o \
  $K/proc.o \
  $K/getprocs.o \ <-- just here, Warning, you not must add any character after '\' but a new line.
  $K/swtch.o \
  ...
```